# Multiple Vimeo videos with FlexSlider JS

Tags: php, javascript, vimeo, flexslider, froogaloop

I hope someone can help. I've searched and searched for a solution to this, and I've played around with the Javascript, but it's just beyond me. I'm hoping that someone else can understand this.

[FlexSlider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) does a great job as a carousel, but if you want multiple videos I can't get them to stop the FlexSlider animation, or stop playing automatically if the user triggers the next carousel slide.

It's easily enough to do with one. The following Javascript shows how this is done. But as you can see, it relies on the element having an ID. The problem is that I have an unknown amount of videos. Sometimes there could be one. Sometimes there could be 20.

If there any way of modifying the code below so that it could handle any number of videos?

```
var player = document.getElementById('player_1');

$f(player).addEvent('ready', ready);

function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false)
    } else {
        element.attachEvent(eventName, callback, false);
    }
}

function ready(player_id) {
    var froogaloop = $f(player_id);
    froogaloop.addEvent('play', function(data) {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider("pause");
    });
    froogaloop.addEvent('pause', function(data) {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider("play");
    });
}    

$(".flexslider").flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationSpeed: Modernizr.touch ? 600 : 1000,
    slideshowSpeed: 3500,
    controlsContainer: "#carousel",
    useCSS: false,
    start: function(){
        $(".flex-control-nav").css("margin-left", "-" + $(".flex-control-nav").width()/2 + "px");
    },
    before: function(slider){
        $f(player).api('pause');
    }
});
```

The PHP/HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
    <?php  for($i=0;$i<$slideCount;$i++) { ?>
        <li>
            <?php if($slides[$i]["type"] == "1") { ?>
                <div class="video">
                    <iframe id="player_1" width="1000" height="500" frameborder="0" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo $slides[$i]["URL"]; ?>?api=1&player_id=player_1"></iframe>
                </div>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <a href="explore.php?item=<?php echo $slides[$i]["slideID"]; ?>">
                <img src="static/images/slides/<?php echo $slides[$i]["slideID"]; ?>/<?php echo $slides[$i]["URL"]; ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($slides[$i]["headline"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); ?>" width="868" height="488"  /></a>
            <?php } ?>
<       /li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Possible solution:** Run the FOR loop and count the number of Videos, then create a number of different instances of `$f(player)` in Javascript. Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm about to embark on a similar journey. Any answers now that it is 3-4 months later?

Comment: Sadly not. I think we ended up changing it in the end. The problem was giving each video its own reference. Simple if you know how many videos you'll have!

Answer (score 4):

I know you said you've moved on, but I was having difficulty getting all the videos to be able to pause automatically when moving on to the next slide, and came across this code from Juanfra Aldasoro (http://juanfra.me/2012/08/flexslider-multiple-videos-v2/) that creates the necessary jQuery for each video, then I believe all that would be left to do is counting and naming the iframe ids.  Here's his code:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() { 
    var vimeoPlayers = jQuery('.flexslider').find('iframe'), player;        

    for (var i = 0, length = vimeoPlayers.length; i < length; i++) {            
            player = vimeoPlayers[i];           
            $f(player).addEvent('ready', ready);        
    }       

    function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {           
        if (element.addEventListener) {                 
            element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false)            
        } else {                
            element.attachEvent(eventName, callback, false);            
        }       
    }       

    function ready(player_id) {             
        var froogaloop = $f(player_id);             
        froogaloop.addEvent('play', function(data) {                
            jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider("pause");          
        });             
        froogaloop.addEvent('pause', function(data) {               
            jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider("play");           
        });         
    }  

    jQuery(".flexslider")     
    .flexslider({       
        animation: "slide",
        useCSS: false,       
        animationLoop: false,       
        smoothHeight: true,       
        before: function(slider){         
            if (slider.slides.eq(slider.currentSlide).find('iframe').length !== 0)
                  $f( slider.slides.eq(slider.currentSlide).find('iframe').attr('id') ).api('pause');       
        }   
    });

});
```

Hope this helps someone landing here :)